# panda groupby ID, and compute radius with respect to the center of the coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a panda dataframe `df` with the `id`, and the physical coordinates `(x, y)` of groups of particles.
I want use panda dataframe with these steps: groupby with the `id`, compute the distance `R=np.sqrt((x-x_c)**2+(y-y_c)**2)` of each particle from its center.
`x_c` and `y_c` (center coordinates) are computed from:

```
df2=df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['x','y'].mean()
df2.columns=['id', 'x_c', 'y_c']
```

From this dataframe:

```
          id       x         y        
0         33434.0  57580.40  65684.5  
1         33434.0  57580.10  65684.8  
2         33434.0  57580.20  65684.6  
3         33434.0  57580.40  65684.8  
          ...       ...      ...
817526  5621337.0  37264.00  53945.2  
817527  5621337.0  57161.90  65303.3 
817528  5621337.0  57287.80  65933.2  
817529  5621337.0  58111.30  66987.5
```

I want to obtain this dataframe:

```
          id       x         y        R
0         33434.0  57580.40  65684.5  0.21505813
1         33434.0  57580.10  65684.8  0.21505813
2         33434.0  57580.20  65684.6  0.10606601
3         33434.0  57580.40  65684.8  0.17677669
          ...       ...      ...
817526  5621337.0  37264.00  53945.2  17707.67
817527  5621337.0  57161.90  65303.3  5220.65
817528  5621337.0  57287.80  65933.2  5630.37
817529  5621337.0  58111.30  66987.5  6895.2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `group` the dataframe by `id` and `transform` the columns `x` and `y` using `mean` then subtract the transformed mean from the columns `x` and `y` to center each particle, then use the `distance` formula to calculate the resulting column `R`

```
c = ['x', 'y']
df['R'] = ((df[c] - df.groupby('id')[c].transform('mean')) ** 2).sum(1) ** 0.5
```

---

```
               id        x        y             R
0         33434.0  57580.4  65684.5      0.215058
1         33434.0  57580.1  65684.8      0.215058
2         33434.0  57580.2  65684.6      0.106066
3         33434.0  57580.4  65684.8      0.176777
...
817527  5621337.0  57161.9  65303.3   5220.657327
817528  5621337.0  57287.8  65933.2   5630.379935
817529  5621337.0  58111.3  66987.5   6895.229767
```

Comment: what if I want re-compute the center only for those coordinates whose R< value? can you help me? I'm trying to figure it out, but I don't succeed